# c# empty textboxs after click

Tags: c#

I have this problem where I run my code and it gives me empty text boxs and I'm not sure why. I have debug it and found that `number = double.Parse(txtTableAvgTemp.Text);` and `poolCost = double.Parse(txtTableDollars.Text);` are both returning NULL. The code is to work out the heating cost of the pool in question as per size.

```
const double poolLengthMin = 5; // min pool length
     const double poolLengthMax =50; // max pool length
     const double poolWidthMin = 2;  // min pool width
     const double poolWidthMax = 20; // max pool width
     const double poolDepthMin = 2;  // min pool depth
     const double poolDepthMax = 4;  // max pool depth

     // variable used in btnCalculate_Click
    float poolLength;
    float poolWidth;
    float poolDepth;
    float SurfaceArea = 0;
    float Volume = 0;
    const int poolSize = 0;
    const int smallPool = 500000 ;
    const int mediumPool = 1500000;
    const double poolTemp = 1.5;
    double poolDegreesMin = 5;
    double poolDegreesMax = 25;
    double number;
    double costToHeatPool;
    double heatingVolume;
    double poolDegrees = 5;


    /* validation statements for pool
     * length, width and depth
     */
    bool ValidPoolLength(double poolLength)
    {
        if (poolLength >= poolLengthMin && poolLength <= poolLengthMax)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool ValidPoolWidth(double poolWidth)
    {
        if (poolWidth >= poolWidthMin && poolWidth <= poolWidthMax)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool ValidPoolDepth(double poolDepth)
    {
       if(poolDepth >= poolDepthMin && poolDepth <= poolDepthMax)
       {
            return true;
       }
       else 
       {
            return false;
       }
    }
    // end of validation statements

    private void lblCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   // convert variable to float from double from string
        poolLength = float.Parse(txtLength.Text);
        poolWidth = float.Parse(txtWidth.Text);
        poolDepth = float.Parse(txtAvgDepth.Text);


        //clear string 
        txtVolume.Clear();
        txtSurfaceArea.Clear();
        txtTableDollars.Clear();


        // error massages for pool length
        //pool width and pool depth

    if (!(ValidPoolLength(poolLength)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Length measurement is invalid \r\n Please enter a value between : " + poolLengthMin + " and " + poolLengthMax, "Pool Lenght Invalid" , MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
    }
    if (!(ValidPoolWidth(poolWidth)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Width measurment is invalid \r\n Please enter a value between : " + poolWidthMin + " and " + poolWidthMax, "Pool Width Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return;
    }
    if (!(ValidPoolDepth(poolDepth)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pool Depth is invalid \r\n Please enter a value between : " + poolDepthMin + " and " + poolDepthMax, "Pool Depth Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return;
    }
        // caclulate surface area and show in txtSurfaceArea

        SurfaceArea = poolLength * poolWidth;
        txtSurfaceArea.Text += SurfaceArea;

        //calculate pool volume and show in txtVolume
        Volume = poolLength * poolWidth * poolDepth * 1000;
        txtVolume.Text += Volume;


        //calculate size of pool Small, Medium or large
        //and show in lblcategory

     Volume = float.Parse(txtVolume.Text);
     if (poolSize <= smallPool && smallPool >= Volume)
     {
        lblCategory.Text = "Pool Category: Small";
     }
     else if (poolSize <= mediumPool && mediumPool >= Volume)
     {

        lblCategory.Text = "Pool Category: Medium";
     }
     else
     {
       lblCategory.Text = "Pool Category: Large";
     }


        //cost to heat the pool to 25 degrees


     while (poolTemp >= poolDegrees && poolTemp < poolDegrees)
    {
        number = poolDegrees + poolTemp;
        txtTableAvgTemp.Text +=  number.ToString() + "\r\n";
        poolDegrees += poolTemp;

        //variable for costing out heating of pool

        double poolCost = costToHeatPool;
        heatingVolume = float.Parse(txtVolume.Text);
        costToHeatPool = float.Parse(txtVolume.Text);
        poolCost = double.Parse(txtTableDollars.Text);//empty ?
        number = double.Parse(txtTableAvgTemp.Text);//empty ?
        poolCost = (Math.Truncate(poolCost));


            //formula for costing of heating to pool
            costToHeatPool = (25 - number) * heatingVolume / 32500;
            txtTableDollars.Text += poolCost + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

I have given you my whole code as I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. I did try `poolDegreesMin` and `poolDegreesMax`.

Comment: can you add an example of the contents of the textboxes?

Comment: Are you sure you've seen `double.Parse(txtTableAvgTemp.Text)` returning `null`? It returns `double`, and double can't be null.

Comment: the content of the averg temp text box is the water temp starting at 5 degress and add 1.5 up to 25 degrees and the per month text box works out the cost to heat the pool with 'costToHeatPool = (25 - number) * heatingVolume / 32500;' hope this helps oh you enter the pool width, lenght and depth then the caclulate surface area and volume of water.

Comment: @Andy when i debug it and hover over it its just a empty string it just say txtTableDollars.Text= ""

Comment: @warwick, oh. got your point. From your question it was not clear it was `txtTableAvgTemp.Text` not `double.Parse(` of it  is null.

Comment: @Andy sorry i'm just so confused tonight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just see some problems with the parsing itselve. You parse the text of `txtTableAvgTemp.Text`.
This text is extended for each while loop with a new line of temperature:

`txtTableAvgTemp.Text +=  number.ToString() + "\r\n";`

This will never parse.

Further on, on the first cycle the text is empty (`""`, which is not `null`). This will also throw a FormatException.

Initialize the text box first with a `0`. And don't add new lines to a text box if you want to parse from them later. You should use temporary double fields to store the last values. Then there is no need for parsing the whole time.

```
// init with 0
txtTableDollars.Text = 0;
txtTableAvgTemp.Text = 0;
double currentCost = 0;

// do them outside, no need to do it on every loop
float heatingVolume = float.Parse(txtVolume.Text);

// working while
while (poolDegrees >= 3.5 && poolDegrees < 23)
{
    poolDegrees += poolTemp;

    double costToHeatPool = (25 - poolDegrees) * heatingVolume / 32500;

    currentCost += costToHeatPool;

    txtTableAvgTemp.Text += poolDegrees + System.Environment.NewLine;
    txtTableDollars.Text += currentCost + System.Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Additional point: I do not know exactly, but this while loop here looks realy suspicious

```
while (poolTemp >= poolDegrees && poolTemp < poolDegrees) {/*...*/}
```

For me this looks like a `while(false)`. Is this intended? this loop should never be executed...

Comment: no the while loop should be executed to give me the aveg temp and cost. I have to use parse as that is what is called for in my assignment but i can try that. I have tryed to initialize both txtboxes with 0 but did not work. I will try your idea and see if i can get that to work. Still learning

Comment: the 2 variables in the while loop are: poolTemp and poolDegrees, where poolTemp is a `const double 1.5`. poolDegrees is either smaller, equal or bigger. poolDegrees starts too with a value: 5. Therefore it is always bigger than poolTemp. But then, the first part of the while will be always false (`poolTemp >= poolDegrees`) And the while loop gets never executed... If I miss something, please tell me...

Comment: @Andreas yes what your saying is so true i'm just so confused on how to do this id did have `(poolDegrees >= 3.5 && poolDegrees < 23)` but it would not parse . So i asked the instructor for help and he said that i had poolDegrees wrong.

Comment: added a small idea of the while loop to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the beginning of your code there is line of code:

```
txtTableDollars.Clear();
```

is clears textbox, so later when you're using that text, obviously it is empty:

```
poolCost = double.Parse(txtTableDollars.Text);
```

And later in the same loop - you're assigning it like

```
txtTableDollars.Text += poolCost + "\r\n";
```

so if your loop will be executed more than once - you will get some strange result (or exception) when parsing it again.

It looks like you should divide your computation from visualisation. Parse your input once and use numbers for computation, don't reparse text values again.